# Covering a non-rectangle shape with s2sphere/Python

Tags: python-2.7, geometry

I am having a hard time figuring out how to create a region that would be defined by a set of geographical coordinates (more than 4) using s2sphere for Python 2.7.
Does anyone have an idea how i could do this?

Comment: What library are you using? What attempt have you made?

Comment: I am using s2sphere [link] (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/s2sphere). I have tried a lot to see if there were any built-in function to create Polygon but there seem to be nothing about this.